# C# WinForms disable DPI scaling

Tags: c#, winforms, scale, dpi

I have a WinForm application which hosts many images. When I put the application on a Win7 machines that has a DPI of 120, it completely ruins the look of the form. Is there a way to disable the scaling for my form?

I am aware that this is something that is not advised and that DPI should be seamless and handled by the OS. But when it comes to a skinned application, the images do not scale well. I do not have the luxury of creating images for all the DPI variations, so please don't suggest that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have bigger problems when you change the AutoScaleMode property.  Increasing the DPI also changes the system font size.  Necessarily so, font sizes are expressed in points, 1/72 inch.  The fonts need to be bigger to get the same point size when the DPI increases and keep the text just as readable when viewed from the same distance.

Since the controls don't get resized anymore, the text on, say, a button no longer fits.  One way to battle this is to change the font size on the controls proportionally.  Easy if you let all the controls inherit the form font, just changing the form's Font property automatically updates the controls as well.  The clear disadvantage is that the user will have a harder time reading the text.  This especially gets bad when the DPI goes to 150 dots per inch and beyond, your UI just turns into an unusable postage stamp.

Yes, background images need to get scaled to fit the larger control or form.  A pixel in the image now no longer maps one-to-one to a pixel of the monitor.  The default Graphics.InterpolationMode value does a fairly decent job of filtering the image.  But it depends on the kind of image how well that turns out.  A photo almost always scales very well.  Finely detailed line art and text does not.  Picking the right kind of image goes a long way to avoiding having to create separate ones.

This problem isn't going to go away until monitors start to have the kind of resolution a printer has.  We're still a long way from 600 dpi for desktop monitors.  Phones will be first.

Comment: 600 DPI screens are becoming reality. Just look at your phone (ok, not 600 but 480 are here). The future is here.

Answer (score 11):

Create a application manifest file (right-click on project/ add/new item/application file) and uncomment this section:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

Creds to this site: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-

Comment: This worked for me. The form is still to big for my laptop screen but at least it is not now being shrunk and making some controls inaccessible.

Answer (score 9):

Adding one line of code before the auto-generated call to InitializeComponent in the Form1-constructor solved it for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        // Make the GUI ignore the DPI setting
        Font = new Font(Font.Name, 8.25f * 96f / CreateGraphics().DpiX, Font.Style, Font.Unit, Font.GdiCharSet, Font.GdiVerticalFont);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all on Windows 10 with a 150% scaled 4K monitor

Comment: Combining this with setting AutoScaleMode to None solved the problem for me

Comment: doesn't work on windows 10 with 150% or 200% even with `AutoScaleMode = None`

Comment: This solved it for me on Windows 10 (1809) 150% scaling

Comment: Using `actualPixelSize * 100f / CreateGraphics().DpiY` worked for me. This should compensate for any DPI scaling.

Comment: @Pieter12345 - excuse me, what is "actualPixelSize"? Can you explain how to determne this variable?

Comment: @S.H. `actualPixelSize` is the pixel size that you choose a component to be. You essentially undo the current DPI scaling, placing it back at 100%.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `AutoScaleMode` property of the form to `None`.

Comment: Combining this with manually scaling the fonts of the controls (as suggested in another solution here) solved the problem for me.