# How to fix the size of a C# Windows Form Application from resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Windows Form application that I am working on and when I build the form on the development PC it looks fine but when I move the exe onto another machine everything resizes. This then through's out the picturebox and button controls. I have specified the size of the controls in VS but it seems to ignore these. I have also fixed the minimum and maximum sizes to be the same but this has not resolved the issue.

Can anyone point me the direction of something that I have missed as I need to fix the size of the controls.

Thanks in advance.

New PC[image]

Development PC
[image]

```
this.interviewPb.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject("interviewPb.Image")));
this.interviewPb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(771, 366);
this.interviewPb.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
this.interviewPb.Name = "interviewPb";
this.interviewPb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(393, 492);
this.interviewPb.TabIndex = 9;
this.interviewPb.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: Do you have some screenshots?

Comment: The minimum height of Textboxes, Buttons and so on is controlled by the font size.

Comment: Presumably your app is scaled. check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009150/c-sharp-winforms-disable-dpi-scaling)

Comment: probably the other machine has different DPI configuration than yours.

Comment: I recommend switching to WPF if dpi is going to be a common problem.

Comment: Post code, at least for one of the pictureboxes, from your InitializeComponent() method in the Designer.cs file.  If you see the Font property being set then that's the problem.

Comment: @RobertSnyder How would that help?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Going to WPF will fix _all_ of your problems instantly without writing a single line of code!!1!

Comment: @UweKeim Yes, I noticed that already. My project man-hours have decreased to near zero. All I need to do is create a new WPF project in VS - done.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar granted you will have a lot of code changes to make it work, but WPF is not affected by the DPI settings if done correctly. It is somethign that I had to overcome in one of my projects I have for work where many of the computers my program was going to run on had different DPI settings as well as very different screen resolutions. So I mention it because it is worth looking into

Comment: @UweKeim Of course there is going to have to be work done and many more man hours into a project. Nothing is that easy. I know the OP was asking for a answer in the winforms world, but it is a situation that I had to deal with, and switching to WPF was the fix for my solution. Many hours later I don't have the same resolution/dpi errors I was facing with winforms. Hence why I made the comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the [`AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for the form to `none`. This should prevent resizing even if the DPI resolution is different on different machines.

Comment: Also do this for all nested (user) controls which have this `AutoScaleMode` property.

Comment: @UweKeim Or you can set `Inherited`

Comment: This is, in general, rather bad advice.  It doesn't stop Fonts from getting rescaled, their sizes are expressed in points.  So they don't fit their controls anymore.  Ignoring "retina" displays is something else that everybody will regret, soon.

Comment: @HansPassant That's true - but so is trying to keep the same control size for different DPI resolutions, which is what the OP is asking. I'd rather say that the original requirement should be reconsidered.

Comment: In my projects, I always specify font sizes in pixel. Will change that in 15 years back to DPI when Windows actually supports Retina resolutions well enough.