# My program's GUI is messed up in Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8

I have created a wallpaper changing program in C# using Visual Studio and I have had a couple reports in this last few months of part of the program not displaying right. I have no clue what is causing it. Any help?

**This is what it looks like on my computer, Windows 7**
[image]

**This is what it looks like on the victims computer, Windows 8**
[image]

Comment: If this is WinForms then what form border style have you set?

Comment: @ScruffyDuck Yes it is a Windows Forms Application, as for Border Style it is Fixed Single.

Comment: Hmmm - I have problems with missing controls in Win7 when I use some border types but I don't think this is the issue in your case.  I don't have win 8 so I can't make any tests

Comment: Anchors are the other thing that can cause problems

Answer (score 2):

If this is a windows Forms application,  it could have something to do with DPI/resolution scaling.  This isn't unique to Windows 8.

Check the Display sizing options match on both displays (or simply change on your Windows 7 Machine) in Control Panel.

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display for Windows 8.  (I think it is the same for Windows 7).

See [C# WinForms disable DPI scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009150/c-sharp-winforms-disable-dpi-scaling)

or

[How to write WinForms code that auto-scales to system font and dpi settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I got to go atm but I will check it out in a few hours and get back to you if I run into any problems.

Comment: This has always been a problem in C#, even in the days ofWinXP.  It happens if you set the display to anything other than 100% or 96dpi.

Comment: I forgot about this one - I had a lot of older users who change the font display and ended up with missing buttons.