# Winforms appearing different size to design

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I've created a simple windows form in the designer and not modified any of the design code. Yet, when I launch it, some controls are bigger than they should be and the window is the wrong size. I've tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24529874/4700841) but it makes no difference.

[image: GIF of Issue]

Could you please advise on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Which controls exactly are bigger than expected and what size does the window have (and what size do you expect)? I can't see anything wrong in the GIF. What OS are you running on and do you have scaled screen settings?

Comment: If you look at the GIF the listbox is too big and hids the status bar (that's the most obvious one, the rest are all too big too I think). I'm running Windows 10 and I've tried both with and without the "fix blurry text" options. My "make everything bigger" setting is 250% but surely windows should handle all this? I've never had these problems before.

Comment: Is the list box really too big (i.e., what size is it set to have)? The designer gives you only a preview. Results at runtime may vary. So, the question is: Which of your settings does the runtime apparently violate? Have you used proper layout containers and mechanisms (e.g., the `Dock` property for the status bar)?

Comment: use maximum size and minimum size properties to fix components size

Comment: As you have scaling set to 250% you may need to opt in to the new Windows 10 [High DPI Scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Your application is not DPI Aware, your Form scales to Font and is subject to virtualization. See [these notes I've written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other?answertab=active#tab-top) and this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top).